# Fujitsu LifeBook AH-532 compatible with 9.5mm HD?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

My nephew has a [Fujitsu LifeBook AH-532](http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/products/computing/pc/notebooks/lifebook-ah532/) laptop, purchased Oct-2013. His HD appears to have died, and we're taking the opportunity to upgrade to a better HD - faster, and also 1TB.

We're thinking about this one: [Seagate SSHD 1TB MLC/8GB Sata III ST1000LM014](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/laptop-hard-drives/laptop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/?sku=ST1000LM014#specs) - that's the only SSHD [available locally to me](http://ksp.co.il/?uin=21195). However, its height is 9.5mm, and the local link says the drive may not fit all laptops. I believe it will, since it's quite a large laptop, and http://www.laptoppartsexpert.com sells [Fujitsu LifeBook AH532 Hard Drive Replacement (9.5mm 320GB SATA 5400RPM)](http://www.laptoppartsexpert.com/i-17260504-fujitsu-lifebook-ah532-hard-drive-replacement-9-5mm-320gb-sata-5400rpm.html)

Can anyone confirm that the AH-532 can accomodate a 9.5mm HD? Any other comment about compatibility, or the drive in general?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I bought the drive, and it fit well and appears to work fine. The original drive - [Toshiba MK5061GSYN](http://storage.toshiba.com/storagesolutions/client/mkxx61gsyn-series) - is 9.5mm high as well.